# document.querySelectorAll() helper function not working

Tags: javascript

Im trying to use a document.querySelectorAll() helper function as defined [here](https://plainjs.com/javascript/selecting/select-dom-elements-by-css-selectors-4/) couse I'll be using it a lot.

Wher running this I get an error saying :

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined*

So my question is why is this not working?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>    
<title>Javascript tutorial</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
    <p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
    <p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
    <p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
    <p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function selectElement(el) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(el);
}

window.onload = function() {
    var someElement =  selectElement('.test');
    someElement.style.backgroundColor='red';
}
```

*Updated with a **for loop***

```
function selectElement(el) {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll(el);
    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        return element[i];
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    var someElement =  selectElement('.test');
    someElement.style.backgroundColor='red';
}
```

This should be working...right? :)

Comment: Where are we getting `someVar` from?

Comment: querySelectorAll() returns a list of DOM elements that match a given CSS selector, you need to loop through each node to apply changes

Comment: Might be obvious, in the update you are using a different class

Comment: If you want all the `.test` elements to have red backgrounds, why not just add that property to the CSS rule for `.test`?

Comment: ".container" was a typo...I changed it. Still not working.

Answer (score 3):

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns a HtmlCollection. If you want to apply a style to all of the paragraphs, you'll have to loop over the collection:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.test'), function(val) {
  val.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

```html
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
```

You can use `[].forEach.call()` to turn the HtmlCollection into an array, and loop over it. Then apply the style to all the elements that were matched by the `querySelectorAll()` call.

Comment: Why do `[].slice.call(foo).forEach` when you can just do `[].forEach.call(`?

Comment: Thank you @torazaburo, didn't know I can call it like this, too

Comment: It would be better to set `backgroundColor`. Setting `background` will potentially set all the other background-related properties which are part of the `background` shorthand property.

Comment: Never had this, but you're right, that's more exact.

Answer (score 0):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns array-like collection of Nodes, so you need to use iterate over the nodeList collection and add the properties to each elements.

> Returns a **list of the elements** within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

1. `someVar` in your script is not defined
2. You can use `DOMContentLoaded` instead of `load` event
3. For this case you can use CSS instead of Javascript

```js
function selectElement(el) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(el);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var someElement = selectElement('.test');

  for (var i = 0; i < someElement.length; i++) {
    someElement[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
```

**CSS**

In case, if you just want to set the styles of all the elements having class `test`

```css
.test {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
```

**DOMContentLoaded**

```js
function selectElement(el) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(el);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var someElement = selectElement('.test');

  for (var i = 0; i < someElement.length; i++) {
    someElement[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
<p class="test">I'm a paragraph</p>
```

Comment: That is quite fine Tushar, but that's not what I expected. On plainjs.com site it says : That when creating helper function an naming it "function $(){}" you can use $(...) to fetch elements just like you would with jQuery; you can even pass in a context element".

Comment: @VikVikVik Yes, you can, but that doesn't mean you can use it like jQuery, you still need to iterate over collection

Comment: @michael Right, I've updated. Wrong choice of words :)

Comment: Just to be exact.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`style` is a property of an HTML Element

`querySelectorAll` returns an (array-like) HTML collection of all the matching HTML Elements.

You need to loop over the return value and set the `style` of each element *in turn*.

For example, from the first code example on the page you link to:

```
for (i=0; i<matches.length; i++)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this work than?

    function selectElement(el) {

 var element = document.querySelectorAll(el);

 for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {

  return element[i];

 }

}


window.onload = function() {

 var someElement =  selectElement('.container');

 someVar.style.backgroundColor='red';

}

Comment: @VikVikVik — You are looping over the collection, hitting the first element in it, and returning that. If you want to change all of them, you need to return the whole collection and then put your style change inside your loop